# Why does WIF configuration in one RP allow access to other RP on same server?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, wif

I have a custom STS built with WIF 3.5.  I have 2 relying parties on the same server.  The config follows:

RP1:

```
  <audienceUris mode="Always">
    <clear />
    <add value="https://server1:1843/RP1/" />
  </audienceUris>
  <federatedAuthentication>
    <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://server2:1743/" realm="https://server1:1843/RP1/" requireHttps="true" />
    <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" />
  </federatedAuthentication>
```

RP2:

```
  <audienceUris mode="Always">
    <clear />
    <add value="https://server1:1643/" />
  </audienceUris>
  <federatedAuthentication>
    <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://server2:1743/" realm="https://server1:1643/" requireHttps="true" />
    <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" />
  </federatedAuthentication>
```

With this config everything works as expected.  If I log into RP1 and then browse to RP2 I get redirected to the STS on server2.  However, if I change the config for RP 1 as follows:

```
<cookieHandler requireSsl="true" path="/" />
```

after logging into RP1 when I browse to RP2 I am not redirected to the STS on server2 and I can access RP2.

Why would this configuration in RP1 allow or deny access to RP2?

Answer (score 3):

The default path value is `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath`
When you didn't specify path, each RP got it's own cookie and authentication in one RP didn't affect the other. When you have specified a cookie path value of "/", it's applicable to both RP1 and RP2. So the authentication cookie that is stored on the client when you logged into RP1 is re-used for RP2 also.
So, you are automatically logged into RP2 and RP2 no longer does a re-direct for authentication.

Comment: That's exactly the reason, a cookie shared between applications.